# Can not find module TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typescript, mean-stack

I am converting my nodejs project into typescript nodejs. I have changed the extensions of .js files to .ts, however now I am getting **require()** errors. To overcome this problem, I tried

```
import express from "express"
```

However this gives me **"Can not find module error"**. I have researched it and narrowed it down to the issue where I guess TypeScript needs **express.d.ts** file for detecting the Express module. However I couldn't find the **express.d.ts** file anywhere in my project. Which ultimately means I am missing something.

Can somebody point me in the right direction or perhaps help me resolve this problem?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/express/express.d.ts) can you find your missing file

Comment: I tried to generate the .d.ts file using typescript compiler's declaratoin command, however it doesn't work since, the express file is of .js extension instead of .ts

Comment: Maybe [this](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/typescript-with-visual-studio-2015) article could help you.

Comment: do you have typing installed?

Comment: `npm i -g tsd`
`tsd install express --save`

Answer (score 0):

Typescript can't find module declarations, that's why you get a (semantic) error.
The code actually compiles and should work without errors.
However, autocompletion and type inference won't work.

To fix the error, you should install `express.d.ts` as an ambient module declaration file.
This can be done using **[Typings](https://github.com/typings/typings)**:
`npm install -g typings`
`typings install express --global --save`